# Is events like 'click' are macrotasks?

Tags: javascript, event-loop

code:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log(1), 10);
for (let i = 0; i < 3e9; i++) {}
console.log(0);
window.onclick = () => console.log('click');
```

When this script is run:

- If I do NOT 'click' while synchronous code on line 2 is running console shows expected result:

  ```
  0
  1
  ```
- If I 'click' while synchronous code on line 2 is running console shows unexpected result:

  ```
  0
  click
  1
  ```

So I have 2 questions:

1. If 'click' is a macrotask then it should get into macrotask callback queue after setTimeout? So that when synchronous code is finished, stack is empty, macrotask callback queue put console.log(0) in stack, stack executes it, then callback queue puts console.log('click') in stack and stack executes it.
2. If I click when synchronous code from line 2 is running, why I see 'click' in console at all? I clicked before executor reached the line 4...

Comment: Are you sure that code's actually running? It only takes a second or so to finish that loop on my machine in Node.

Comment: you may increase 3e9 to 10e9 to run it longer

Comment: I suppose it depends on if your browser interrupts tasks or not. Could be a feature of the [event loop](https://javascript.info/event-loop).

Comment: That's just 3s vs. 1s. Why not an infinite loop instead?

Comment: I've read that article exactly before this post. There author saying that mousemove is macrotask like setTimeout.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not entirely sure either. I usually avoid blocking with long-running tasks so this problem is moot, but you do have an interesting question. I hadn't seen the distinction before.

Comment: 3s or 1s does not matter. The question is why click happening not after setTimeout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are various [task-queues](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#task-queue), which will all have different priorities, set by the User-Agent (UA).

The first step of the [Event Loop's processing model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model:event-loop) is to choose a task from any of these tasks-queues, that's where they can decide that even if a task actually has been queued after an other one, they can pick it, as long as they aren't queued on the same task-queue.

The [timer task source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-task-source) is often one of the less prioritized ones, and the [UI task source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#user-interaction-task-source) one of the most prioritized ones.

That's what you are experiencing here.

Note that there is a proposal for an API allowing us web-devs to have access to this prioritization system: https://github.com/WICG/main-thread-scheduling/blob/master/PrioritizedPostTask.md

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log("timeout"), 0);

if( window.scheduler ) { // try to use the Prioritized postTask API
  scheduler.postTask(() => console.log("low priority task"), { priority: "background" });
  scheduler.postTask(() => console.log("normal priority task"), { priority: "user-visible" });
  scheduler.postTask(() => console.log("high priority task"), { priority: "user-blocking" });
}
else {
  console.log( "The Prioritized postTask API can be enabled from chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features" );
}

// queue on the message task-source (faster than timeout)
const { port1, port2 } = new MessageChannel();
port1.onmessage = () => console.log("message");
port2.postMessage("");

// block for 3 full seconds
const start = performance.now();
while( performance.now() - start < 3000 ) {}
console.log(0);
```

In Chrome with the `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features` flag set on, this results in

```
0
high priority task
normal priority task
message
timeout
low priority task
```

To be 100% honest, the task prioritization may not be what makes the message event and the "normal" task fire before the "timeout" in my snippet. The [timer-initialisation-steps algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps) actually is itself asynchronous and asks the UAs to queue that task while [*in parallel*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#in-parallel) (step 14). So this task *should* anyway be queued after other tasks that are queued synchronously.

Note also that most UAs <sub>(at least Chromium and Firefox)</sub> have a starvation system in place, avoiding a queue to eat all the resources without letting the other queues to ever execute their tasks.

---

Also, to answer the title of the question, an Event is not a task, you can very well fire an Event synchronously, from the same task (e.g using `EventTarget.dispatchEvent`).

---

And for the second bullet question,

> "If I click when synchronous code from line 2 is running, why I see 'click' in console at all? I clicked before executor reached the line 4..."

that's simply because the UA will proceed the JavaScript job until its end before even *queuing the task* that will dispatch the Event to all its targets and finally call all their callbacks. So at that time, your event handler is well defined, as is its callback.

Comment: Can you please check my answer I have a different result then the one you wrote while having the feature enabled.

Comment: @MuhamedKarajic yeah, this answer was written more than 2 years ago, what was "experimental" by then probably made it to stable, or got ridden of. The point of the answer is that you shouldn't expect any fixed behavior here and that it's normal. There is a prioritization system, you can't interfere with it.

Comment: Edited: By me the execution is shown below in Google Chrome version 118.0.5993.88 and I have had enabled the flag in chrome so called "Experimental Web Platform features". -> 


//3 seconds freez,
0
microtask
high priority task
timeout
normal priority task
message
low priority task

P.S: I have also tried it without the macro task and its the same.